# For Base64 encode, prefer str.encode('base64_codec') or base64.b64encode(str)?

Tags: python, codec

In Python library, there is base64 module for working on Base64. At the same time, if you want to encode a string, there is codec for base64, i.e. `str.encode('base64_encode')`. Which approach is preferred?

Comment: I think `str.encode('base_64_encode')` is kind of a historical accident (I only expect to see *character encodings* there), and I would stick to `base64.b64encode(str)`.

Comment: Yeah, how did you even find the encode version?? If you search for 'python base64', you land immediately on http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html.

Comment: @ckhan, it is mentioned here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings, scroll down passe the list of 'real' encodings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it may work for Python 2:

```
>>> 'foo'.encode('base64')
'Zm9v\n'
```

Python 3 doesn't support it:

```
>>> 'foo'.encode('base64')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: base64
```

And in terms of speed (in Python 2), the `b64encode` method is about three times faster than `.encode()`:

```
In [1]: %timeit 'fooasodaspf8ds09f8'.encode('base64')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit b64encode('fooasodaspf8ds09f8')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 564 ns per loop
```

So in terms of both speed and compatibility, the `base64` module is better.

Comment: The performance difference alone is enough to justify using b64encode.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, there's another option that works in both Python 2.4+ and 3.2+:

```
>>> from codecs import encode
>>> encode(b'fooasodaspf8ds09f8', 'base64')
b'Zm9v\n'
```

This also enables encoding/decoding gzip and bzip2 among other things.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms

http://wingware.com/psupport/python-manual/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#improvements-to-codec-handling